# Android way to check my activity's windowstate - background

Tags: android

I have a chat app, when my app is in the background (called HOME button), my app is running countiniously...

When on my app a user initiate a private chat with me, i d like to showing up a notification.

So **how I can check in my app, that my app is in the background**?

Leslie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use onPause in your chat activity:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Another activity is taking focus (this activity is about to be "paused").
    //set a flag somewhere (in your service?) to say activity has been minimised
}
```

See the [Activity lifecyle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle) docs for more details.

Comment: Also, if you aren't currently using a service (it isn't clear from the question), you absolutely need to do that. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html